# How to ignore the double quotes while concatenating a number as a string in between a string using python?

Tags: python

I have a variable "cnt" which gets incremented in every iteration and I am concatenating the value to a string but I dont want the double quotes .

For example:

```
cnt=1234
str1="tti -c "+'"something,MID="'+str(cnt)+'",ID=Udm5gIgAf1;"'
```

When I am printing `str1`,I am getting output as below

```
tti -c "something,MID="1234",ID=Udm5gIgAf1;"
```

But I want like

```
tti -c "something,MID=1234,ID=Udm5gIgAf1;"
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure those double quotes are because you have them as characters in your string

try

```
str1="tti -c "+'"something,MID='+str(cnt)+',ID=Udm5gIgAf1;"'
```

Answer (score 1):

`str1="tti -c "+'"something,MID='+str(cnt)+',ID=Udm5gIgAf1;"'`

You have double-quotes surrounding your other pieces of the string, not around your number. So remove those as I wrote it above.

However, why do you even have the concatenating of the second piece here at all? Why not just `str1="ttti -c "something, MID=' + str(cnt) + ',ID=blahblah;"'`

Better yet, use f-strings:
`string1 = f'tti -c "something,MID={str(cnt)},ID=Udm5gIgAf1;"'`

Answer (score -1):

Make sure to use remove them from the string! After take a look and they should have disappeared.

Answer (score -1):

Anyhow the use of `f-string` will make your life easier

```
f'tti -c \"something,MID={cnt},ID=Udm5gIgAf1;\"'
```

or

```
f'''tti -c "something,MID={cnt},ID=Udm5gIgAf1;"'''
```

Comment: No need to use backslashes or triple quotes here.

Comment: yes, but it is more readable - for me